# Invalid string syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the following code crash?

I'm following along with the tutorial, and it seems my version is a bit newer than the one I'm following. The syntax I wrote makes complete sense to me, yet claims that it's invalid syntactically:

```
var1 = "Hello world! "

print var1
```

or:

```
print "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `print` is a function, so you have to *call* it.

For example,

```
print('hello world')
```